# Using Hooks. Thematic

Tags: custom-field, customization

I've added some custom fields to pages and trying to figure out the best way to display them.

I was thinking I could use the get_field() option and hook into a sidebar, but am not really sure how to do this.

EDIT---
Ok sorry folk, I apologize for not being specific.

I am adding custom field options to each page in my theme using this plugin http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/

I was using short-codes previously to add the content into a specific page, but know I need it globally. I figured the easiest way to do this would be to hook into the side bar but an more sure exactly how to do this.

The other option is to go into the loop, but I would rather leave that alone if I can.

So my question is, how do you hook into a sidebar widget using functions.php?

Comment: Please be more specific as to your goals.  Also, please show us what you've tried, and where you're running into trouble.

Comment: Could you pleaes explain more.

Comment: So my question is, how do you hook into a sidebar widget using functions.php?